# What is the Spring equivalent for CDI's Instance, or Guices Provider

Tags: java, spring, guice, cdi

In CDI you can define an object that will give you items of a certain type, using:

```java
@Inject
Instance<MyObject> myObjectInstance;
//...
MyObject myObjectInstance.get();
```

Similarly in Guice you can do:

```java
@Inject
Provider<MyObject> myObjectInstance;
//...
MyObject myObjectInstance.get();
```

I am wondering if there is a similar construct in Spring, or you must use the `ApplicationContext` in order to get the reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So after a lot of digging around I found out that Spring supports JSR-330. This JSR defines a simple API - the whole spec is literally just this API - that standardizes several dependency injection interfaces, annotations and behaviors.

Unlike Spring's `FactoryBean` the `javax.inject.Provider` interface doesn't throws Exception on getting the bean reference. Furthermore, you would still need to define this FactoryBean in some place (read XML, or `@Configuration` class, and this is suboptimal).

Due to a bug, in current Spring 3.1.1, the `javax.inject.Provider` *does not work*. It *does work* in Spring 3.1.0.

In order to use it you simple need to include the `javax.inject` `jar` - if you use maven you can:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring will detect it, and from that moment on you can simply:

```
@Inject
Provider<MyObject> myObjectInstance;
//...
MyObject myObjectInstance.get();
```

like in the Guice example, since it is the same API.

Despite my previous comment to Konstantin, Spring *does create* the Provider by itself. (I was testing it against Spring 3.1.1 and run into this [Spring Provider regression issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9388))

Comment: I fear there are significant differences between Provider<> and Instance<> (hope i am wrong). First: Instance implements Iterable and this has a big impact on how do you use it. E.g. a regular use for me is to declare @Inject Instance<Interface> xxx ... so i'll can iterate through instances of each class that implements interface without know classname. I'll want to know how to do this using Provider.

Comment: `Instance<>` is not a part of JSR-330, and is not a part of Spring either. The problem that I had at the time was to get prototype beans (that depend on some context variables) without getting a hold on the applicationContext itself.

Comment: [Here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33127576/1426227) related to the differences between `Provider` and `Instance`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [FactoryBean](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/09/whats-a-factorybean/)

Comment: Not really. In order to autowire a `FactoryBean`, you need an actual implementation for it. From what I can tell I should use `ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean` but it sounds like too much work for no good reason.

Comment: And what about lookup-method with scope="prototype"? Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10358248/1385087

Comment: The problem is that it looks like I must change the XML (I try to do most of my beans via annotations) for every "Provider" instance. I've noticed that Spring supports JSR-330, thus also the Provider interface, except that it doesn't creates these beans on the fly, you need to create those beans on your own - thus it misses the point completely.

Furthermore there is no lookup-method annotation, so I must change the XML & create a new class for every factored bean?

Comment: I think there is no elegant way to avoid new wrapper classes in such a case. There is a bit ugly method for annotation-based configurations (without lookup-method annotation): http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html#method-injection

Comment: I voted you up because you helped me tremendously in finding the actual solution. Unfortunately I wasted a lot of time because of this bug they have in 3.1.1 with the `Provider`s from JSR-330, since I thought they don't create the Provider implementations on the fly.