# When should Instance<T> and Provider<T> be used to inject beans in CDI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I've been reading the API documentation of [`Instance<T>`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) and [`Provider<T>`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/inject/Provider.html), but it isn't completely clear when they should be used.

What's the difference between the following approaches?

```java
@Inject
MyBean bean;
```

```java
@Inject
Instance<MyBean> bean;
```

```java
@Inject
Provider<MyBean> bean;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Provider<T>` is a JSR-330 interface which is extended by the CDI interface `Instance<T>`.

Injecting `MyBean`, your application will throw an exception during startup when there is no matching bean or more than one matching bean.

Injecting `Instance<MyBean>`, bean resolution is delegated to the application: you can iterate over all candidate beans and `select()` the one you want or call `isUnsatisfied()` and decide what to do when there is no matching bean.

For beans with `@Dependent` scope, calling `Instance.get()` will create a new instance for each invocation, and you should invoke `Instance.destroy(t)` for each such instance when you no longer need it.

`Provider` just has the `get()` method, but no `destroy()` or `select()` and does not support iteration. In a CDI environment, for any use case addressed by `Provider<T>`, you had better use `Instance<T>` instead.