# Spring equivalent for CDI Instance

Tags: spring, cdi

I am new to Spring and i need to convert a CDI class to Spring.

I have the below code in CDI

```
@Inject
private Instance<HealthCheck> healthChecks;
```

I then iterate over healthChecks.

I found a similar question [What is the Spring equivalent for CDI's Instance, or Guices Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538528/what-is-the-spring-equivalent-for-cdis-instance-or-guices-provider) , where it was advised to use

```
@Inject
Provider<MyObject> myObjectInstance;
//...
MyObject myObjectInstance.get();
```

However, since provider does not implements iterable, I am not able to iterate.

Can someone please help me on how can I convert the CDI code block to spring.

Comment: Just create a field with type `List<HealthCheck>` and slap `@Autowired` on it.

Answer (score 3):

create a new file spring.factories inside META-INF with following content:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=package_name.CustomApplicationContextInitializer
```

or you can use it in your junit test like:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(initializers = CustomApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

And now you can use like:

```
@Autowired
private Instance<HealthCheck> healthChecks;
```

**CustomApplicationContextInitializer.class**

```
public class CustomApplicationContextInitializer implements
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

        // Configure custom CustomAutowireCandidateResolver to handle CDI
        // Instance<T> dependency requests
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.setAutowireCandidateResolver(new CustomAutowireCandidateResolver());
    }
}
```

**CustomAutowireCandidateResolver.class**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

public class CustomAutowireCandidateResolver extends ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver {

    static final boolean IS_CDI_INSTANCE_CLASS_PRESENT = ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.enterprise.inject.Instance", null);

    @Override
    public Object getLazyResolutionProxyIfNecessary(DependencyDescriptor descriptor, String beanName) {

        if (IS_CDI_INSTANCE_CLASS_PRESENT && Instance.class.equals(descriptor.getDependencyType())) {

            // TODO refactor getLazyResolutionProxyIfNecessary to allow to
            // customize lazy dependency resolution for Instance<T>
            return getInstanceAdapterFor(descriptor);
        }

        return super.getLazyResolutionProxyIfNecessary(descriptor, beanName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private Object getInstanceAdapterFor(DependencyDescriptor descriptor) {

        ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory = (ListableBeanFactory) getBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) listableBeanFactory;

        // Instance<TargetType>
        Class targetType = descriptor.getResolvableType().getGeneric(0).getRawClass();
        Map<String, Object> beansOfType = listableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(targetType);

        List<Bean> beansInstances = beansOfType.entrySet().stream() //
                .map(e -> new Bean(e.getValue(), registry.getBeanDefinition(e.getKey()).isPrimary()))//
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Annotation[] qualifiers = retainQualifierAnnotations(descriptor.getAnnotations());

        Beans beans = new Beans(targetType, beansInstances);
        return qualifiers.length == 0 ? beans : beans.select(qualifiers);
    }

    private Annotation[] retainQualifierAnnotations(Annotation[] annotations) {
        return Arrays.stream(annotations) //
                .filter(a -> a.annotationType().isAnnotationPresent(Qualifier.class)) //
                .toArray(Annotation[]::new);
    }

    static class Beans<T> implements Instance<T> {

        private final List<Bean> beans;
        private final Class<?> type;

        public Beans(Class<?> type, List<Bean> beans) {
            this.type = type;
            this.beans = beans;
        }

        protected List<Bean> getBeans() {
            return beans;
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            return (T) findDefaultInstance();
        }

        protected Object findDefaultInstance() {

            List<Bean> beans = getBeans();

            if (beans.size() == 1) {
                return beans.get(0).getInstance();
            }

            Object highestPrioBean = returnPrimaryOrHighestPriorityBean(beans);

            if (highestPrioBean != null) {
                return highestPrioBean;
            }

            // TODO figure out a sane default to use here - maybe throw an
            // exception?
            return beans.get(0).getInstance();
        }

        private Object returnPrimaryOrHighestPriorityBean(List<Bean> beans) {

            long highestPriority = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            Object highestPrioBean = null;

            for (Bean bean : beans) {

                if (bean.isPrimary()) {
                    return bean.getInstance();
                }

                // TODO figure out to retrieve order from BeanDefinition /
                // BeanDeclaration

                Object instance = bean.getInstance();
                Order order = instance.getClass().getAnnotation(Order.class);
                if (order != null) {
                    if (order.value() > highestPriority) {
                        highestPriority = order.value();
                        highestPrioBean = instance;
                    }
                }

                Priority priority = instance.getClass().getAnnotation(Priority.class);
                if (priority != null) {
                    if (priority.value() > highestPriority) {
                        highestPriority = priority.value();
                        highestPrioBean = instance;
                    }
                }
            }

            return highestPrioBean;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Instance<T> select(Annotation... qualifiers) {
            return select((Class<T>) type, qualifiers);
        }

        @Override
        public <U extends T> Instance<U> select(Class<U> subtype, Annotation... qualifiers) {
            return new Beans<U>(subtype, filterBeans(subtype, qualifiers));
        }

        protected List<Bean> filterBeans(Class<?> subtype, Annotation... qualifiers) {

            List<Annotation> requiredQualifiers = Arrays.asList(qualifiers);

            return getBeans().stream() //
                    .filter(bean -> subtype.isInstance(bean.getInstance())) //
                    .filter(bean -> bean.getAnnotations().containsAll(requiredQualifiers)) //
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public <U extends T> Instance<U> select(TypeLiteral<U> subtype, Annotation... qualifiers) {

            // TODO implement (Class<U> subtype, Annotation... qualifiers) via
            // select(TypeLiteral<U> subtype, Annotation... qualifiers)
            return select(subtype.getRawType(), qualifiers);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return getBeans().stream().map(bean -> (T) bean.getInstance()).iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isUnsatisfied() {
            return getBeans().isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAmbiguous() {
            return getBeans().size() > 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy(Object bean) {

            if (bean instanceof DisposableBean) {
                try {
                    ((DisposableBean) bean).destroy();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Bean {

        private final boolean primary;
        private final Object instance;
        private final List<Annotation> annotations;

        public Bean(Object instance, boolean primary) {
            this.primary = primary;
            this.instance = instance;
            this.annotations = Arrays.asList(instance.getClass().getAnnotations());
        }

        public Object getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        public boolean isPrimary() {
            return primary;
        }

        public List<Annotation> getAnnotations() {
            return annotations;
        }
    }
}
```

here is full source link: https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-cdi-instance-example