# Does Spring Context have equivalent of Java CDI's @Inject @Any

Tags: java, spring, ejb, cdi

In Java CDI there is great functionality on gathering all managed beans, that share a supertype. Let's say I what to gather all managed instances of MyInterceptor, I just have to write:

```
@Inject
@Any
Instance<MyInterceptor> myInterceptors;
```

Similar functionality I was able to obtain when I was working on EJB, although solution there was way less pretty (I needed to call BeanManager).

**Can similar functionality I can obtain working on @Component's managed by Spring context?**

**[Edit]**
Why is not a duplicate of [What is the Spring equivalent for CDI's Instance, or Guices Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538528/what-is-the-spring-equivalent-for-cdis-instance-or-guices-provider)
*From my understanding, in the above question, there is a hidden assumption, that I have both contexts: Spring and CDI, which may not be always the case (especially in Java SE applications). Furthermore, I have a bad experience in mixing contexts, they often claim that they are compatible, but it isn't always the case. You can get trapped in unexpected problems, like this: https://blog.akquinet.de/2017/01/04/dont-get-trapped-into-a-memory-leak-using-cdi-instance-injection/*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Spring equivalent for CDI's Instance, or Guices Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538528/what-is-the-spring-equivalent-for-cdis-instance-or-guices-provider)

Comment: @Slaw I've added an answer to the head post.

Comment: Define a property `List<your-type>` or array `your-type[]` and spring will inject all beans of that type. Which is also explained in the reference guide (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the the field as a `List` with a generic type `MyInterctptor` you should be able to achieve what you are looking for. Ex:

```
@Autowired
List<MyInterceptor> interceptors;
```

More info can be found here: https://dzone.com/articles/load-all-implementors