# Spring Autowired in new java object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am starting to work with Spring Boot and got a question about how to autowire Spring Beans in java Objects that are not managed by Springs application context.

Scenario: In my Spring Boot application I want to code a scheduled task, that first fetches a list of master data of type "environment" from the database. For each "environment" object multiple asynchronous Rest calls will be executed which return some JSON Data (here "applicationServerData"). This data should be kept locally until all rest call responses arrived. After some processing the result will be written to the database.

So I thought of creating some kind of processor class that is capable of holding the requested data locally. For each environment a new object will be created with the new operator:

```
@Slf4j
public class EnvironmentProcessingServiceImpl implements
    EnvironmentProcessingService {

@Autowired
private DataManagementFacade dataManagementFacade;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "mock")
private ProductionDataClient productionDataClient;

private Environment environment;

private List<ApplicationServerDataHolder> applicationServerDataHolderList;

public EnvironmentProcessingServiceImpl(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
    this.applicationServerDataHolderList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The problem now is, that `@Autowired` wont work, because the objects are not managed by Spring, but i can not simply make it a `@service` because I need multiple instances if I want to hold data in the same class. I read about a solution with the `@Configurable` annotation. Is this good practice?

Or should I make the class a `@service` and make another component that caches all the data and is wiped after the task finished to have empty lists for the next run?

What do you think is good practice in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A @service in Spring can be scoped to Prototype,@Scope("prototype"), check here : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/

Comment: would you suggest some kind of factory than to get new Instances?

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358035/cleaner-way-to-get-new-instance-of-an-autowired-field-that-is-prototype-in-natur

Comment: Thanks! this seem to fit well for my use case!

Answer (score 0):

You want to get different instance according to the different situation,I think you should have more Impls for one interface,right?  You can use the interface to Autowired,but you should make a decision about which instance you want get,Spring cannot do the choice ,it just help manage the beans.eg, when the type=0,you get bean A;when type=1,you get bean B;  Before you use @Autowired ,your spring should have deposited the bean .one way you can use ,the other way  you can use the .and the bean's scope is Singlton default .Just my answer.

Comment: No, the implementation is always the same. Only the Environment object that is passed to the Service differs, but the processing is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring without the Boot part. One trick that you can do if you can get your hands on the context object somehow is to call:

```
context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean);
```

In our project we have a manually crafted context lookup mechanism that we mostly don't need to pass around. I actually try to avoid autowire in favor of injecting things in `@Configuration` classes and making those the only place I deal with Spring and have Spring related imports. The exception is our jersey resource classes. Those are instantiated by jersey and not by Spring. I know there are some elaborate hacks to fix and make the two frameworks play nice with each other. But instead I just implemented a static method that returns the static singleton context and creates it if it doesn't exist. Added advantage is that it vastly reduce the amount of magic that happens on startup (spring is nice until it doesn't work and doesn't tell you why).

```
public class InbotSpringContextLoader {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InbotSpringContextLoader.class);
    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = null;

    private static final AtomicBoolean contextCreated = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private static final Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

    public static ApplicationContext context() {
        if(contextCreated.get()) {
            return context;
        } else {
            LOCK.lock();
            try {
                if(!contextCreated.get()) {
                    // init SLF4j JUL bridge
                    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
                    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();

                    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RootConfig.class);

                    contextCreated.set(true);
                }
                return context;
            } finally {
                LOCK.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use this from jersey resources and other places where getting the context is kind of sucky
     * 
     * @param bean
     *            the bean where stuff needs to be injected
     */
    public static void autowire(Object bean) {
        InbotSpringContextLoader.context().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(bean);
    }

    public static void destroy() {
        if(context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In my resource constructors I simply call.

```
InbotSpringContextLoader.autowire(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the ApplicationContext from any component:

```
@Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

then you can use this to get a bean:

```
Class<?> clazz = DemoBean.class;
DemoBean demoBean = (DemoBean)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowire(clazz, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO, false);
```

Note that with AUTOWIRE_NO, any member variables annotated with @Autowired will still be autowired.